# Tokyo Tower's illumination changes almost daily to celebrate something. How to know what?

Tags: tokyo, architecture, events

Tokyo Tower's illumination changes almost daily to celebrate various events:

- A soccer game in which the Japanese team is playing.
- The visit of a foreign president.
- Support for a tragedy somewhere in the world.
- Doraemon.
- etc.

During my visit, how to know what today's illumination is celebrating or commemorating?

Answer (score 12):

This official website of Tokyo Tower has an English-language calendar:

https://www.tokyotower.co.jp/lightup/en.php

It details for each day's illumination:

- Its name, for instance today is "*Magic Halloween Diamond Veil*",
- A picture of the illumination,
- The start/end times of the illumination.

[image: Magic Halloween Diamond Veil]